# Несколько INSERT в одном запросе

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Есть несколько запросов один за одним. Я их пытаюсь выполнить все вместе.

```
INSERT INTO words (`word`,`length`) SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'ROUTEROS', 8) AS tmp0 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT `word` FROM words WHERE `word` = 'ROUTEROS' );
INSERT INTO words (`word`,`length`) SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'ROUTER', 6) AS tmp1 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT `word` FROM words WHERE `word` = 'ROUTER' );
```

Имею ошибку
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO words (`word`,`length`) SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'ROUTER', 6) AS tmp1 W' at line 2

Выполнять по очереди 100-200 запросов одинаковых как-то слишком глупо.

Comment: делаете поле word уникальным и `insert IGNORE into words ... values('XX',1),('YY',2)` или так же но `on duplicate key ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как сказал @Mike так и помогло.

```
insert IGNORE into words values('XX',1),('YY',2)
```